# Building SSIS Packages in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

I think this is about as basic question as I can have, but what version of Microsoft Visual Studio and what packages do I need to install in order to create SSIS Packages that I can install in SQL Server to run in scheduled jobs? I have done this before, but now whenever I download Visual Studio my toolbox is empty and I cant seem to find any of my data flow tasks no matter what I install. Any help would be much appreciated as this basic task has me a bit frustrated.

Comment: [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Likely SSDT but if you're only SQL Server 2005/2008/2008R2, you're going to access it through the install media and it'll be referenced as Business Intelligence Design Studio/BIDS

Comment: I am Management Studio 18. I will give SSDT a change. Thank you.

Comment: Another question, can I do this from Visual Studio Community or will I need to use a paid for version?

Answer (score 1):

For VS2017 and earlier versions, you can easily find it after [creating an SSIS project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-1-creating-a-new-integration-services-project?view=sql-server-2017#create-a-new-integration-services-project).

In a solution where includes SSIS project:

[image]

For VS2019, as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) states the required functionality to enable `Analysis Services`, `Integration Services`, and `Reporting Services` projects has moved into the respective `Visual Studio extensions`.

To find SSIS Toolbox in your VS2019:

1. Download the extension for SSIS here
2. Create a new SSIS project and you can find the ToolBox